# Is it possible to override component's severity colors by using createTheme?

Tags: material-ui

I would like to modify MUI Chip color and background color "globally" but using different colors than the ones defined in the same theme for severity.

This is what actually looks like (only by using theme defined severity colors):

[image: Two stacked MUI Chip component elements. The above one is green and it says "Activo". The bottom one is red ant it says "Inactivo"]

This is how I want it to look:

[image: Two stacked MUI Chip component elements. The above one is light green and it says "Professional". The bottom one is light red ant it says "Rejected"]

It's actually possible to achieve that by using createTheme module or I need to take a different approach?

This is my attempt:

```js
export const defaultTheme = createTheme(
  {
    palette: {
      // Palette definitions
    },
    components: {
      MuiChip: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            severity: {
              success: {
                color: colors.success.main,
                backgroundColor: colors.success.light,
              },
              // And so on with the remaining severity levels
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the background color in the theme, you can add a name to the theme, I provide you with an example and let you try.

```js
export const yourTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        successChip: {
            contrastText: '#5ccc09',
            main: '#eaf9e0',
        },
        rejectChip: {
            contrastText: '#ff595d',
            main: '#ffe9ea',
        }
    }
});
```

```js
<Chip label="Professional" color="successChip"/>
<Chip label="Rejected" color="rejectChip"/>
```

And then you will get what you want it to look like.

[image]